# executing a script on multiple command output

Tags: unix, sh, ksh, aix

i have a script that identifies users who modified a file the script usage is

```
Usage: /data/scripts/who.sh "file" [number of days]
```

i can't make any changes on this script so i tried Something like :

```
x=$(find /data/files/* -mmin -60) && /data/scripts/who.sh $x 1
```

so i would have the users who modified the files in the last 60 min. the problem is that there are multiple files that are modified and the usage of the script who.sh takes only one file.

is there a way to Apply the script who.sh on every file of the output of the command :

```
find /data/files/* -mmin -60
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `-exec` primary for that.

```
find /data/files/* -mmin 60 -exec /data/scripts/who.sh {} 1 \;
```

Comment: thank you it works now i'll just add it on a cron with mail notification :)